# How can access particular String from Resource file with using Resource.getString(id) in Android

Tags: android, resources

I want to know that I have the string.xml Resource file which contains status messages. Now I want to process them according their id. I have written the following code but it fails on `Message = res.getString(Msgid);` and logs `Resource not found Exception`.

Can any one help me?

```
public void FileStatusMsg(int Msgid)


        {
                String Message = null;
                Resources res = this.getResources();


                Message = res.getString(Msgid);

                //Display Status Messages..
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OfficeLinQ.this);
                builder.setMessage(Message).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(
                        "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                            {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
```

Comment: What is your msgid? How do you obtain it?

Comment: What are you passing as Msgid?

Comment: Where is the value of Msgid coming from? It seems like it isnt actually a resource ID.

Comment: yes it was not Resource id. I corrected it now and providing Resource id in Msgid and then it works....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a value

```
<string name="msg">Message</string>
```

inside `strings.xml`.

To access this value, in your activity give:

```
this.getText(R.string.msg).toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access it by using this method :

```
YourActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.myString);
```